# How to fix .htaccess error? Keeps asking for authentication

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, .htpasswd

I'm setting up basic http authentication for my dev site with `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`.

First, I created my `.htpasswd` user and password (https://shop.alterlinks.com/htpasswd/htpasswd.php MD5).
Then, my htaccess file with some basic configurations.
I placed both my `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files in my `php_site_project` folder (I know it's not safe, but I did it for testing first the authentication).

Also in my apache configuration file, I have `AllowOverride All`

```
AuthuserFile /home/my_user/public_html/php_site_project/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require user admin
```

After all those configurations, I cleared my cache and tested on Chrome, it keeps asking me for user and password over and over... On Firefox asks just once but doesn't let me enter either.

By the way, I don't have logs on this problem.